# How do I get Azure AD B2C's built-in claims to be returned in the token when I'm using a custom policy?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I've been using the built-in SignUpOrSignIn policy for a while, but I'm now moving to a custom policy.

When I set up the built-in policy, I was able to choose from a list of built-in application claims (like `displayName` and `jobTitle`), and select which ones I wanted to be returned in the token when the user signed in.

Now I'm setting up the custom policy I want to do the same thing, but I can't get it to work.

So far, in `TrustFrameworkBase` I have added a `ClaimType` of `jobTitle`:

```
<ClaimType Id="jobTitle">
    <DisplayName>Job Title</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Job title.</UserHelpText>
</ClaimType>
```

I've added the following `OutputClaim` to the `TechnicalProfile` with ID `login-NonInteractive`:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" PartnerClaimType="jobTitle" />
```

And I've added the following `OutputClaim` to the `TechnicalProfile` with ID `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email`:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
```

But the `jobTitle` claim doesn't come through with the others in the token. I've done the same for `given_name` and that does work. If I change the first `OutputClaim` to:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
```

then a `jobTitle` claim *does* come through, but with the value of the `given_name` claim. This implies I'm just using the wrong `PartnerClaimType` but there doesn't seem to be a list of them anywhere.

How can I get the built-in job title attribute to be returned as a claim in the token when the user signs in using their local B2C account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to read the **jobTitle** claim (or other claims) for the user and then issue it (or them) in the token, then you must:

1) Declare the **jobTitle** claim:

```
<ClaimType Id="jobTitle">
  <DisplayName>Job Title</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="job_title" />
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="job_title" />
  </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
</ClaimType>
```

2) Add the **jobTitle** claim as an output claim to the **AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId** technical profile:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
  ...
  <OutputClaims>
    ...
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
  </OutputClaims>
  ...
</TechnicalProfile>
```

3) Add the **jobTitle** claim as an output claim to the relying party technical profile:

```xml
<RelyingParty>
  ...
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    ...
    <OutputClaims>
      ...
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
    </OutputClaims>
    ...
  </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

Comment: This works for some other attributes like `displayName` and `givenName`, but it doesn't seem to work for `jobTitle`.

Comment: OK I figured out the problem - I'd removed the step from my UserJourney which gets the extra attributes using that `AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId` technical profile. Not sure why I did that. Adding it back in makes it work. Thanks!